# Refresh arp entries in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, arp

In Linux, an ARP entry's age gets reset/refreshed if a packet comes by. However, it seems that FreeBSD simply sets a timer, and unconditionally evicts the ARP entry even if packets with that MAC-address/IP came by. Is there a way to get Linux's behaviour of updating the age if traffic is seen?

I am experiencing large bursts of ARP broadcast traffic every 20 minutes on my LAN because of this.  I know that one can change the age in FreeBSD's cache, but that just changes the intervals between bursts.  I want to stop the bursts in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about FreeBSD is that things are documented: [arp(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arp&apropos=0&sektion=4)

We have:

> These routes time out periodically (normally 20 minutes after
>   validated; entries are not validated when not in use)

...and...

> max_age          How long an ARP entry is held in the cache
>                    until it needs to be refreshed.  Default is
>                    1200 seconds.

I read that as if we see the entry within `maxage` then it is validated. That is: When in use it is validated.

So if you do a:

```
arp -i ixl0 -a
? (192.168.1.2) at 00:00:00:00:00:00 on ixl0 expires in 237 seconds [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.1) at 00:00:00:00:00:01 on ixl0 permanent [ethernet]
```

You will see the arp entries and their age. If you want to extend the cache duration simply change `max_age`.

Comment: I know about the max age, I've also tried to explain how this still differs from, e.g., Linux' implementation and many other platforms. I get an enormous arp broadcast storm each 20 minutes.. doesn't really matter if this is every 20min or every hour

Comment: I think you have a different problem. But as you have already explained everything including the required answer - good luck with that. Asking a question and including the facts might gain more traction.

Comment: Indeed, there is a deeper problem in my scenario, but all other possible solution are a dead end. But I don't think I gave the answer myself.. unless you think I should ditch pfSense for a linux-based distro